# sql row_number stay the same unless a criteria is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

First time post here, and I've done a bunch of searches to find this but don't know the terminology to search for to begin with. I have a table in SQL Server 2012 containing timesheet data with these columns: `Name, ID, ENTEREDONDTM, EVENTDATE, STARTDTM, ENDDTM, STARTREASON, ENDREASON`

I'm trying to do a `row_number` where the value in row_number stays the same unless `StartReason = 'newShift'` in which case I would like for it to increase by 1.

My end goal is to find a total shift length per shift and I know how to do those calculations based on `startdtm` and `enddtm`, but there is no current column with a `shiftID` for me to group by.

Comment: not clear enough for me... is there a second record with the end time for this same shift? or is it all on this same record?

Comment: Here is a little more info (I don't know how to post a sample data table in here).

startdtm would be when they clock in and enddtm is when they clock out, start reason is why they clocked in. So they could have a record that is startdtm = 8am (in datetime format) and enddtm =12pm and startreason = newShift
The next row would be startdtm = 12:30pm and enddtm = 4pm and startreason = 30minbreak. 
The next row would normally be the next shift and we only know that based on startreason = newShift. Endreason always is out so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Rank ()` windowed function, partitioned by StartReason and add +1 (to reserve the first).
Before use this value, you can use a case to compare the value.

Exemple: `case StartReason when 'newShift' then 1 else Rank () over (Partition by StartReason ) +1`

Comment: I don't want when newShift to always be 1. I want it to be 1 only when it's the first newShift then I want every subsequent row to be 1 until another newShift appears. Then I want the second newShift to be 2 and every row between that and the next newShift to be 2.

Comment: I was able to tweak what you provided to do mostly what I wanted. The shift IDs are a little odd because they are the row number for that particular employee and not necessarily the next shiftID, but since I'm grouping by them and they don't matter otherwise, I'll just ignore it.

Comment: ;with GroupByEmployees AS
(
SELECT ID, [STARTDTM], [ENDDTM],[STARTREASON],[ENDREASON],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY cast([StartDTM] AS datetime)) AS EmpPunchNum
FROM [dbo].[BigLots_Perez_20160208_Punch]
)
,
FindShiftID AS
(
SELECT *, case StartReason when 'newShift' then Rank () over (partition by id order by ID, EmpPunchNum) else 0 end as ShiftID FROM GroupByEmployees
)

SELECT *,
CASE ShiftID when '0' then LAG(ShiftID, 1) OVER(Partition by ID Order by ID, emppunchnum) else ShiftID end as FinalShiftID
FROM FindShiftID
order by id, EmpPunchNum